# Trying to use JavaMail

Tags: java

So I'm trying to create a server where I can change the sender email to whatever I want. I've tried signing up for a free SMTP server but I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do what I'm trying to do. If this does not work could someone lead me to a SMTP server that would allow me to do this?

```
package Mailer2;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message.RecipientType;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
public class mailer2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AddressException, MessagingException{
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "ssrs.reachmail.net");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, new Authenticator() {

            // Override method to Authenticate to mail server
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("MCA28\\admin", "NotShowingPassword");
            }
            });

        session.setDebug(true);

        MimeMessage Msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        Msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("yo@yo.com"));

        Msg.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, "emailtosend@gmail.com");

        Msg.setSubject("afa");

        // Initiate MimeBodyPart for filling email content
        MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messagePart.setText("Message Content");
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messagePart);
        Msg.setContent(multipart);

        // Email Sending process
        Transport.send(Msg);

    }



}
```

Here is the log:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "ssrs.reachmail.net", port 587, isSSL false
220 ssrs.reachmail.net rmsmtp 3.1.0a 4a1db2f953
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "ssrs.reachmail.net", port: 587

EHLO 192.168.1.4
250-EASYSMTP
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 102400000
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 STARTTLS
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "102400000"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "PLAIN LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<yo@yo.com>
503 error: not authorized, use AUTH
DEBUG SMTP: got response code 503, with response: 503 error: not authorized, use AUTH

RSET
250 ok
DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending, THROW: 
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 503 error: not authorized, use AUTH
;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 503 error: not authorized, use AUTH

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1609)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1117)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at Mailer2.mailer2.main(mailer2.java:51)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 503 error: not authorized, use AUTH

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1616)
    ... 4 more
QUIT
221 bye
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 503 error: not authorized, use AUTH
;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 503 error: not authorized, use AUTH

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1609)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1117)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at Mailer2.mailer2.main(mailer2.java:51)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 503 error: not authorized, use AUTH

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1616)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: "MCA28\\admin" isn't likely to be a valid username for an SMTP service. You need to set more properties, specifically the ones that define authorization, which as the messages are telling you is presently not enabled. Have another look.

Comment: When i emailed the SMTP host he said that the username is supposed to be MCA28\admin. But since \ is an escape char i had to use 2 of them. Do you think it's possible that they do not allow me to forge a new email address? Or is their a better/different way to authenticate my login?

Comment: The code is missing `prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");`. And depending on the porovider you might need to request SSL as well. The login looks fine, its a normal Windows user name.

Comment: Oh awesome all it works now!

Comment: Ok, then I will put it as the answer. @user3875091

Answer (score 1):

The code is missing `prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");`.

Depending on the provider you might need to request SSL or STARTLS on the mail submission port as well.

Comment: Yea i also had to enable STARTTLS